# Azure databricks update / delete records from Azure Synapse table

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I have a databricks notebook in pyspark/python . And I have a azure synapse database . I would like to update a single records in a Synapse table . Seems for the original

```
df.write \.
format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw") \
```

doesn't have these option . it just have append, overwrite ... so will need another libraries to help ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should load to a staging table in Synapse and then use `.option("postActions",postActionsSQL)` to insert/update/delete into the final table. Here is a [full example](https://bennyaustin.com/2020/02/05/pysparkupsert/).

Answer (score 0):

I would load the output temporarily to ADLS to the file (parquet most probably) and then use polybase or `OPENROWSET` to update records (UPDATE with join or MERGE using mentioned external table).You can create stored procedure  and sync with creation of parquet.

I guess Microsoft would suggest not to use databricks as a separate resource, but rather utilize spark pools within Synapse Studio.